# How I can be notified when a Facebook page - I don't own- published a new post ?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am creating a news app and want to add Facebook pages of news websites. I dont want to pull new posts every 30 minutes for example.  I want to be notified when there is a new post.

I read real time updates
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3

but it says that I must be the owner of the page or I can link my app to that page which I can't do.

Is there any alternative solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one alternative solution: You can use an App or User Token to check for new posts manually with a cron job - by using the [Page Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed) endpoint.

Comment: thanks for reply but I am searching for an automatic way. even if facebook doesnt support that. I hope if there is a service that can manage this and send me pushes

Comment: a cron job IS an automatic way ;)

Comment: I don't mean that. I mean that something notify me once there is a new post. Crone job runs on time basis even if there is no new posts

Comment: but that´s your only chance, unfortunately. just use a cron job that runs every minute, for example.